Python Pandas-Getting the first value of each group
Suppose I have a dataframe df and I am trying to get the least value of each group:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'B': ['1', '2', '2', '4', '1']
})

Using "transform" ('first') will lead to the following result:
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')
        A  B
    0  foo  1
    1  foo  1
    2  bar  2
    3  bar  2
    4  bar  2

However, I was expecting a result like this
    A  B
0  foo  1
1  foo  1
2  bar  1
3  bar  1
4  bar  1

I have tried sorted_values but it didn't work. What can I do to get the result I wanted?

df.groupby("A")["B"].transform("min") ?

Thank you. I was also trying about sorting alphabets, in Stata I can use bysort A (B):replace B=B[1] this applies to numbers and alphabets at the same time
